# Insert special Characters / PHP + MySql + Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, utf-8, special-characters

This question has been asked a lot of times but none of suggested solutions worked for me :(

I need to insert special characters, as ’ (closing apostrophe) for example, into MySql DB via PHP using Android.

**MySql** Table is defined as:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Data is passed to PHP, via **Java**, so:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", value1));       
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", value2));

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("blabla.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

**PHP** receives it so:

```
//To be able to receive UTF-8 (needed?)


mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');

$param1 = $_POST['param1'];
$param2 = $_POST['param2'];

//Convertsion to UTF-8 (needed?)
$param1 = utf8_decode($param1);
$param2 = utf8_decode($param2);

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset('utf8',$mysqli);
$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ...
```

Insert command inserts the record, but special characters becomes "?" in the table.
Any help?

i.e   "A’B" becomes in the DB: "A?B"

Thank you

Comment: Show an example of a small string you send. Then show how php receives that string. So before you put it in the database. And also before you decode it utf8. We want to know first if the database has anything to do with it.

Comment: After `$mysqli` assignment add call: `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");`

Comment: I've edited my question adding set_charset function and an example too. But I continue having that issue! :'(

Answer (score 0):

Removing calls to `utf8_decode` function did the trick!

Answer (score -1):

Try mysqli_real_escape_string() function. This escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, taking into account the current charset of the connection.

**Example:**

```
mysqli_real_ecape_string($mysqli,$param1);
mysqli_real_ecape_string($mysqli,$param2);
```

Comment: He is using prepared statements. No point escaping the strings.